# Rcpp::evalCpp(" ") generates lots of warnings

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, rstan, macos-ventura

R version 4.2.2

RStudio version 2022.12.0+353

macOS Ventura 13.2.1 (M2 silicon)

I was testing some rstan models. The knitted R markdown returns some warning and error messages but still conducts the calculation. So, I tried a simple function that generated many warnings (See below).

```
> Rcpp::evalCpp("1+1") 
In file included from <built-in>:1:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/StanHeaders/include/stan/math/prim/mat/fun/Eigen.hpp:13:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Dense:1:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Core:540:
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/ReenableStupidWarnings.h:14:30: warning: pragma diagnostic pop could not pop, no matching push [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
                             ^
In file included from <built-in>:1:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/StanHeaders/include/stan/math/prim/mat/fun/Eigen.hpp:13:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Dense:2:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/LU:47:
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/ReenableStupidWarnings.h:14:30: warning: pragma diagnostic pop could not pop, no matching push [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
                             ^
In file included from <built-in>:1:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/StanHeaders/include/stan/math/prim/mat/fun/Eigen.hpp:13:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Dense:3:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Cholesky:12:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Jacobi:29:
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/ReenableStupidWarnings.h:14:30: warning: pragma diagnostic pop could not pop, no matching push [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
                             ^
In file included from <built-in>:1:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/StanHeaders/include/stan/math/prim/mat/fun/Eigen.hpp:13:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Dense:3:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Cholesky:43:
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/ReenableStupidWarnings.h:14:30: warning: pragma diagnostic pop could not pop, no matching push [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
                             ^
In file included from <built-in>:1:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/StanHeaders/include/stan/math/prim/mat/fun/Eigen.hpp:13:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Dense:4:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/QR:15:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Householder:27:
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/ReenableStupidWarnings.h:14:30: warning: pragma diagnostic pop could not pop, no matching push [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
                             ^
In file included from <built-in>:1:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/StanHeaders/include/stan/math/prim/mat/fun/Eigen.hpp:13:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Dense:4:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/QR:48:
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/ReenableStupidWarnings.h:14:30: warning: pragma diagnostic pop could not pop, no matching push [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
                             ^
In file included from <built-in>:1:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/StanHeaders/include/stan/math/prim/mat/fun/Eigen.hpp:13:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Dense:5:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/SVD:48:
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/ReenableStupidWarnings.h:14:30: warning: pragma diagnostic pop could not pop, no matching push [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
                             ^
In file included from <built-in>:1:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/StanHeaders/include/stan/math/prim/mat/fun/Eigen.hpp:13:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Dense:6:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Geometry:58:
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/ReenableStupidWarnings.h:14:30: warning: pragma diagnostic pop could not pop, no matching push [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
                             ^
In file included from <built-in>:1:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/StanHeaders/include/stan/math/prim/mat/fun/Eigen.hpp:13:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Dense:7:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Eigenvalues:58:
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/ReenableStupidWarnings.h:14:30: warning: pragma diagnostic pop could not pop, no matching push [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
                             ^
In file included from <built-in>:1:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/StanHeaders/include/stan/math/prim/mat/fun/Eigen.hpp:14:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Sparse:26:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/SparseCore:66:
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/ReenableStupidWarnings.h:14:30: warning: pragma diagnostic pop could not pop, no matching push [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
                             ^
In file included from <built-in>:1:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/StanHeaders/include/stan/math/prim/mat/fun/Eigen.hpp:14:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Sparse:27:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/OrderingMethods:71:
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/ReenableStupidWarnings.h:14:30: warning: pragma diagnostic pop could not pop, no matching push [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
                             ^
In file included from <built-in>:1:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/StanHeaders/include/stan/math/prim/mat/fun/Eigen.hpp:14:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Sparse:29:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/SparseCholesky:43:
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/ReenableStupidWarnings.h:14:30: warning: pragma diagnostic pop could not pop, no matching push [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
                             ^
In file included from <built-in>:1:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/StanHeaders/include/stan/math/prim/mat/fun/Eigen.hpp:14:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Sparse:32:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/SparseQR:34:
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/ReenableStupidWarnings.h:14:30: warning: pragma diagnostic pop could not pop, no matching push [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
                             ^
In file included from <built-in>:1:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/StanHeaders/include/stan/math/prim/mat/fun/Eigen.hpp:14:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/Sparse:33:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/IterativeLinearSolvers:46:
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/RcppEigen/include/Eigen/src/Core/util/ReenableStupidWarnings.h:14:30: warning: pragma diagnostic pop could not pop, no matching push [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
                             ^
14 warnings generated.
ld: warning: -undefined dynamic_lookup may not work with chained fixups
[1] 2
```

After updated RStudio to 2023.03.0+386.

```
ld: warning: -undefined dynamic_lookup may not work with chained fixups
```

**UPDATE**: The warning messages only appear in the knitted markdown if I have loaded the '*rstan*' package in the console. In other words, if I test the R script locally first and then knit the RMD, there will be warnings. But if I open a new session and knit the RMD first, there will not be warnings.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `Rcpp`.  It is the compiler that invokes the warnings, called from a package deploying `Rcpp`.  Try `Rcpp::evalCpp("2+2")`, it likely comes back quietly.  And look into creating `~/.R/Makevars` to add flags to silence the compiler.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. So far, I did not find any related discussion about it. It still comes with `ld: warning: -undefined dynamic_lookup may not work with chained fixups`.

Comment: Might be related to your M2 and/or its `clang` version and settings.  Please do trust me when I say that it is not something `Rcpp` turns on.